# Is WPF suitable for Line Of Business software?

Tags: wpf

I do not know if this type of question can be asked on this site, please let me apologize if it is not relevant.

I'm currently thinking about starting the migration of an application developed in Visual Foxpro to VS. NET. I'm looking at Windows Forms and WPF, and I'm clear about the basics like the differences between them.

**My specific question is whether, as of today, is WPF is an active and growing technology or another tool that died and will have no future support?**

I am very interested in this information because I have some experience windows forms; studying WPF seems interesting, but I would not invest my time in a dead end.

I appreciate any information you can give me.

Comment: Preguntas sobre StackOverflow necesitan estar en Inglés (questions on [so] [should be in English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: and I just translated it to English [courtesy of Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) :-)

Comment: There are a couple of similar topics here which you might find interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244834/what-will-the-future-be-for-wpf-and-silverlight-under-windows-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709662/is-wpf-the-future-of-user-interface-design-should-i-learn-it-now

Comment: Also check out this link :-
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d2773c3-f99f-4fe1-9da1-0ed64cfbca86/value-of-wpf-its-future-scope?forum=wpf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course it's suitable for LOB apps (much more so than the WinForms), and it is a growing technology being updated with every new version of the .NET framework, and with all the control vendors investing heavily into developing and updating their WPF controls.

Future is impossible to predict naturally, but WPF most certainly has a much better future than WinForms and it is, in my opinion, a number one choice for any new thick client project(s) on the Windows platform.

WPF is in so many ways vastly superior to WinForms but even if it was for data binding only it would still be easy to recommend over Winforms.

As a matter of fact, choosing WinForms over WPF at this time would be very similar to choosing VB6 over C# and the .NET Platform.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it really is very valuable information to make the decision.
I tried to rate your response but I am newly registered and do not have enough reputation yet.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 19):

I used to work for an investment bank on Wall Street and many of the applications on the trading floor were WPF. And before I left, they were creating whole new suites of applications in WPF. This was in 2011.

Where I currently am, WPF is where all of the non-mobile projects are or are headed. And the applications are extremely critical; used worldwide.

Hope that helps answer any questions you had about whether people actually use it in the "**real world**".

Comment: Undoubtedly it is a very important fact, wpf is much better than windows forms and I'm glad I can migrate to this technology without short-term concerns.

Thank you very much.